# Installing Stripe with npm not working because of 404

Tags: npm, stripe-payments

I am currently trying to install stripe for my project so I am using the command
`npm install --save @stripe/stripe-node`
but it gives an error:

```bash
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@stripe%2fstripe-node - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@stripe/stripe-node@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I tried to look at the page https://registry.npmjs.org/@stripe%2fstripe-node it says {"error":"Not found"}
Is there a problem with the stripe server or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `@stripe/stripe-node` is not a valid `npm` package. Try this instead:

```bash
npm install stripe --save
```

More info on the official [npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe)